# How do I start designing portlets in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, portlet

Is there any plugins for Eclipse for portlet design and deployment? I have never designed portlets so are there any good tutorials on the web as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a [tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/developing-a-portlet-using-eclipse.html) about portlet development (not portlet deployment though, that would be through an appropriate [eclipse-maven configuration](http://wiki.oss-watch.ac.uk/PlutoNotes))

[Portal eclipse](http://portlet-eclipse.sourceforge.net/) can also help to develop portlet in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://sourceforge.net/projects/portlet-eclipse/

Also, you can try IBM Rational Application Developer, which is IBM's Eclipse based IDE. It's Portlet and portal wizards are good... but R.A.D is not opensource.